# Unable to import pyrosm and r5py even after installing these packages

Tags: python, networkx, geospatial, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am working on a geospatial analysis project and I have been trying to install pyrosm and r5py. I installed both these packages successfully as advised in there documentation. But when I import these packages, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrosm'
```

The same goes for r5py as well. I have wasted a lot of time on this if anyone could help me out please.

Or if anyone suggest some other package for geospatial analysis and accessibility in python that would be fine too. I want to divide a city network into 50 * 50 * 50 hexagonal grid and then connect the centers of those grids to the network. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to install through both pip and conda. As well as tried to install by having a separate conda environment for each package separately. But still I am getting ModuleNotFoundError.

I am on windows.

Steps that I followed for r5py are listed on its official docs site,

```
conda create --name r5py --channel conda-forge r5py
conda activate r5py
conda install --channel conda-forge r5py
```

I am able to install it but when I import r5py in jupyter notebook, i get the following error;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'r5py'
```

Comment: do you have windows ?

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the exact steps you took to install those packages, a [mre] how you use them and the exact error message you get. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I am on windows @حمزةنبيل

Comment: HI @Friedrich I have updated my question including the steps I followed for installation of r5py. Kindly have a look. Thanks

Comment: Did you test it on `.py` ? Are you using `jupyterlab`?

Comment: No I didn't. I am using jupyter notebook not jupyterlab. I did try to import it through ipython interactive shell but still throws the same error.

Comment: @SaroKhan Try with JupyterLab as it was mentioned in the documentation :
`If you want to use r5py in a notebook environment, install JupyterLab `

Comment: Thank you @حمزةنبيل. Importing it in jupyter lab doesn't throw any error.  But I can't test it completely as I am unable to follow the population grid example in the users manual https://r5py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/user-manual/quickstart.html# . I followed the instructions for helsinki but geopandas.read_file(r5py.sampledata.helsinki.population_grid) throws DataSourceError: .: Permission denied.

Comment: I added an answer to close the question

Comment: The problem you mentioned is related  to permission not the installation. It is a new issue .

Comment: the `r5py.sampledata.helsinki.population_grid` is a Path see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to use `r5py` in in a notebook environment as mentioned in [Install using mamba/conda](https://r5py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/installation/installation.html#install-using-mamba-conda) :

```
conda install --channel conda-forge jupyterlab
```

Start JupyterLab using:

```
jupyter lab
```

Comment: Make sure you run `jupyter lab` in the same command window in which you've run `conda activate ...` and `conda install ...`.

Comment: @SaroKhan can you accept the answer to close the question

Comment: Thank you , if you still facing problem with permission. you can create new question